# Rails aws s3 read email with csv attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am setting up an app that will read an email that has a csv attachment from aws s3. I am trying to figure out how to grab the attached csv file and process it. I've searched and can't find anything concrete to work with. I won't know what the csv is going to be named.

I've got a basic read of the body working but no idea how to get the attachment.

```
obj = s3.get_object(bucket: 'mys3bucket', key: myobjectKey)
contents = obj.body.read
      from = contents.match(/(?<=From: )(.*?)(?=\n)/).try(:to_s)
      to = contents.match(/(?<=To: )(.*?)(?=\n)/).try(:to_s)
      subject = contents.match(/(?<=Subject: )(.*?)(?=\n)/).try(:to_s)
```

and i've no idea where to go from here... I am new to Rails btw.

Thanks

Comment: How and where is your email stored?. What library are you using to read the emails?. Since you are here, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example might help in posting better questions

Comment: Emails are stored on amazon s3. I am using aws-sdk library to receive the email.

Comment: What format do you use?. Is it `.eml` or `.json` or `.txt` or any other format?

Answer (score 3):

According to the AWS documentation the mails should be in standard `.eml` format. This means you can use a gem like [`Mail`](https://github.com/mikel/mail) to extract everything you need:

```
mail = Mail.read_from_string(contents)
puts mail.to         
puts mail.from
puts mail.subject
```

Extracting attachments:

```
mail.attachments.each do |attachment|
  filename  = attachment.filename
  file_data = attachment.decoded
  # ...do something with file_data here...
end
```

See more examples in the README:
https://github.com/mikel/mail